# reload angular directive within modal

Tags: angularjs

I am using a modal dialog to render a table with textbox for filtering. The issue I am facing is the data of the table changes depending on from where the modal is triggered. Every time the modal is shown the data changes, but the filter value entered does not go. Can you let me know how to make sure to reload the template dom every time.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your description is confusing, and lack of code doesn't help. Looks like you are bitten by double-binding. Perhaps you can do a copy of your data. That's what we do when we edit the line of a table, to avoid the table to change even if the dialog is canceled.

Comment: Provide us some code please.

Comment: Let me elaborate, I have a modal dialog which contains a table directive with search. The modal gets triggered from multiple places and new data gets populated in the table every time. The issue is that it does not re create the dom so the previous search if entered is retained. What I would like to do is I would like to re compile the directive from controller.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/O89TW59SPpXIXe3Ppf5l I created a plunk, Enter something to search, now I would click on the button to get new data the table does update with the new data but the search item in the text box does not disappear. Basically its just refreshing the data not the whole table. I would like to recreate the table with new data.